# google cloud storage stores only (48 B) for each file

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I am uploading binary jpeg files using html `<form>` on to my python webapp server hosted on Google App Engine. The server method receives the entire image (tried printing stats such as file size/type etc. successfully), but fails to write it to google cloud storage bucket. What ends up on the GCS bucket is a corrupted file of just 48 bytes.

```
def handleUpload(self):

  client = self._get_storage_client()
  bucket = client.get_bucket(config.CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)

  results = []

  for name, fieldStorage in self.request.POST.items():
    if type(fieldStorage) is unicode:
      continue
    result = {}
    fileName = urllib.unquote(fieldStorage.filename)
    blob = bucket.blob(fileName)

    blob.upload_from_string(
        str(fieldStorage.file),fieldStorage.type)

    url = blob.public_url
    if isinstance(url, six.binary_type):
        url = url.decode('utf-8')

    results.append(result)

  return results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Actally it should be fieldStorage.file.read() instead of fieldStorage.file because it reads the file using a temporary buffer and not the whole file at once.